# Imbeddings of $n$-dimensional topological manifolds in $(2n + 1)$-euclidean space

Tags: geometry, manifolds

H. Whitney proved that any $n$-dimensional smooth manifold $N$ can be imbedded in $(2n + 1)$-euclidean space (without any compactness assumption). If we consider the case of topological $n$-manifolds (without any additional structure), can anyone explain how to build a topological imbedding $f\colon M \to \mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ of a TOP manifold $M^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$. Any references ??

Thanks everyone for your help !!

Greetings..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in Munkres' *Topology*, in the section titled "Dimension Theory".  Munkres proves that every compact metric space of [covering dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_dimension) $n$ can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$.  He also proves that any compact $n$-manifold has covering dimension at most $n$, and it follows that every compact $n$-manifold can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$.  (Note: Though Munkres does not prove it, every compact $n$-manifold has covering dimension exactly $n$.